# Code-Push - Clear Rollbacks

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, code-push

I'm using [Code-Push](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/) to manage releases for a Cordova app.  Most releases work well, but occasionally I'll get a rollback or two on a release.

These users will end up rolling back to the previous release.  Is there any way I can get these rollbacks cleared to force the users to try again?

Comment: any update on the above ? Did you got any answer ? Is it possible to clear the previous rollbacks

Comment: Didn't find a way to specifically clear rollbacks only.  There is a way to clear the full release history (including rollbacks): `code-push deployment clear`.  The sync/update methods also have an `ignoreFailedUpdates` flag on Sync Options.  That would cause rollbacks to retry I believe.  Lastly, if you do a manual check for updates (`checkForUpdate`), that will tell you if there is an update that failed install (`failedInstall` flag).  Then you could do something specific in that case if you need to.  But no way to just clear rollbacks after the fact via the CLI.